# Can a JSON data structure be directly saved as a CouchDB document?

Tags: python, json, couchdb

I'm a Python programmer with experience using the json module. I've just meet CouchDB and seems very interesting.

I wonder know if JSON data structures can be directly saved as a CouchDB document.

Thanks,

Comment: -1 ...and I'm wondering if tuples can be stored in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to provide an unique ID that will be used as part of the resource name (URI) when `PUT`ting it or you use `POST` and take an auto-generated ID. You can use any JSON, that does not contain `_id` and `_rev`, because these fields are reserved for CouchDB itself.

Answer (score 0):

couchDB is inteded to work with JSON.
have a look here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#POST
you just POST a json document for storage.

Comment: I'm actually thinking about using python-couchdb package.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB will accept any valid JSON Object as a document.